# Print a specific row in Pandas with column names and values row wise with the correct dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to print out a specific row in my dataframe with the column names and their respective values for that row. This is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv('mortality_inhospital_dataset1.csv')

df1 = df1.set_index('ID', inplace = False)

df1 = df1.loc[125047]

print(df1.fillna(0).to_string())
```

I am getting the following output:

[image]

My desired output is:

outcome: 0

age: 72

gendera: 0

BMI: 37.588179

I am not sure why the int values are coming up as floats. Is there a more efficient of presentable way to output this?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `df1 = df1.loc[125047, ['outcome', 'age', 'genders', 'BMI']]`. To convert float to int use `df1['age'] = df1['age'].astype(int)` or explicitly tell the data types while reading the csv

Answer (score 0):

The default `int` dtype does not allow missing values (`nan`), so if one of the rows has missing values, then `pandas` will encode it as a `float`. As noted in the comment by @Epsi95, it's best to specify dtypes explicitly:

```py
dtypes = {"age" : "Int64", "outcome": "Int64"}
cols_to_show = ['outcome', 'age', 'genders', 'BMI']

df1 = pd.read_csv('mortality_inhospital_dataset1.csv', index_col='ID')

df1 = df1.astype(dtypes)

print(df1.loc[125047, cols_to_show])
```